# java - method doesn't pass the test

Tags: java

I am struggeling with a method, which doesn't pass the test.
I am doing something like caesars cipher and I don't know if is matter of the regex (I don't think so) or anything else.

Here is the code:

```
public String code(String text, int distance){

        if (distance <0){           
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (char character : text.toCharArray()) {
            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile ("^[a-zA-Z\\.]$");      
            Matcher mat = pat.matcher(text);

            if (mat.matches()) {              
                character = Character.toLowerCase(character);           
                int originalAlphabetPosition = character - 'a';
                int newAlphabetPosition = (originalAlphabetPosition + distance) % 26;           
                char newCharacter = (char) ('a' + newAlphabetPosition);             
                result.append(newCharacter);
            } else {
                result.append(character);                          
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Here is the test

```
 assertEquals("bgig.fuurumoiu", pac2Ex4.code("vaca.zoologico", 6));
```

And here is the error

```
Expected :bgig.fuurumoiu
Actual   :vaca.zoologico
```

Other tests that are done

```
void testCode() {
        assertEquals("b", pac2Ex4.code("a", 1));
        assertEquals("d", pac2Ex4.code("a", 3));
        assertEquals("-", pac2Ex4.code("-", 3));
        assertEquals("z", pac2Ex4.code("x", 2));
        assertEquals("a", pac2Ex4.code("x", 3));

        assertEquals("b", pac2Ex4.code("a", 27));
        assertEquals("d", pac2Ex4.code("a", 29));
        assertEquals("x", pac2Ex4.code("x", 26));
        assertEquals("x", pac2Ex4.code("x", 0));

        assertNull( pac2Ex4.code("x", -1));

        assertEquals("bgig.fuurumoiu", pac2Ex4.code("vaca.zoologico", 6));
        assertEquals("bgig.fuurumoiu", pac2Ex4.code("vaca.zoologico", 32));
        assertEquals("afhf ettqtlnht", pac2Ex4.code("vaca zoologico", 31));

        assertEquals("wdap bjcsd! 2020", pac2Ex4.code("hola mundo! 2020", 15));
        assertEquals("wdap bjcsd! 2020", pac2Ex4.code("hola mundo! 2020", 41));
        assertEquals("wdap bjcsd! 2020", pac2Ex4.code("hola mundo! 2020", 67));
    }
```

Where am I doing wrong?
It must be the condition, that is not well done, and this must be cuased by the regex. However, I can't find the error.
I tested my regex in https://regex101.com/ and it works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your matching a single character pattern against the entire string. Will never match.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm just pointing out that the regex will never match because it's designed to match a single character. It just needs to be taken out of the loop and a quantifier like `+` needs to be added after the character class.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Got ya.  I think I read this back to front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You regex does not work in regex101

try `\w*\.\w*`

But still your logic results in `bgigNfuurumoiu`, so change to

```
    if (distance <0){           
        return null;
    }

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile ("\\w*\\.\\w*");      
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(text);
    if (!mat.matches()) {     
        System.out.println("No Match");
        return text;
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (char character : text.toCharArray()) {

        if (character == '.') {
            result.append(character);
            continue;
        }
        character = Character.toLowerCase(character);           
        int originalAlphabetPosition = character - 'a';
        int newAlphabetPosition = (originalAlphabetPosition + distance) % 26;           
        char newCharacter = (char) ('a' + newAlphabetPosition);             
        result.append(newCharacter);
    }
    return result.toString();
```

**EDIT**

do away with regex

```
    if (distance <0){           
        return null;
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (char character : text.toCharArray()) {

        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(character)) {
            result.append(character);
            continue;
        }
        character = Character.toLowerCase(character);           
        int originalAlphabetPosition = character - 'a';
        int newAlphabetPosition = (originalAlphabetPosition + distance) % 26;           
        char newCharacter = (char) ('a' + newAlphabetPosition);             
        result.append(newCharacter);
    }
    return result.toString();
```

Comment: then there are other previous tests that don't pass. I edit and added them to show you.

Comment: so something like `wdap bjcsd! 2020` does not have a dot in it, so it will not natch the regex.  What EXACTLY should your regex match?

Comment: Why even have  regex testing????  Why change your question after people have put in effort??

Comment: as you can see, there are many tests. I thought that once these were passed, I don't need to show them. If the regex changes thank to your support and then I make a step backwards, I think I am still doing the same question but I am showing that some test are testing a character, others a string with '.' and others not.

Comment: see the edit in my answer.  If this answers your question then please kindly upvote and accept.

Comment: yes, I did it as I replied you. Thank you for the support. I appreciate it very much.